# TopologyTestDriver error opening store at location

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I don't know when exactly the unit tests in my project started failing with the following error:

> ProcessorStateException: Error opening store ***myStore*** at location
>   ***aLocation***

This exception was generated by TopologyTestDriver constructor.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I found out the properties going into TopologyTestDriver were different to those from the deployment, so I had to adjust:

```
streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "my/desired/path");
```

After adding this configuration everything worked.